# Click event not firing from href link

Tags: jquery, html, dialog

I have a strange problem that I shall try to explain as best I can. I have a header and in that header there is a menu. When the site first loads, it loads main.php and if I click the link in the menu to open a dialog window, nothing happens. However, if I navigate to another page, the link will work. I am having trouble understanding why this is happening as the menu is loading correctly when the header loads. I would be grateful if anyone could offer some suggestions as to things I can try. This is happening in all browsers. Thanks

**html code**

```
<div class="col_1">    
    <h3>Boxes</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="BA">Add Box(es)</a></li> <!-- This is the culprit. -->
      <li><a href="/domain/admin/requests/boxes/index.php">Administration</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

**jquery code**

```
$(function(){
      $("a.BA").click(function(){
        $("#boxaddform").dialog('open');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `preventDefault` to over-ride the value you've set to the `href` attribute :

```
$("a.BA").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#boxaddform").dialog('open');
});
```

**EDIT** :

After looking at your fiddle, its important that you do one more thing - *initialise the dialog before calling `open` on it*, like this :

```
 $("#boxaddform").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
 });
```

You cant call `open` on a `dialogbox` which doesn't exist.

Updated demo  : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TrScN/8/

OR,

Simply replace  `$("#boxaddform").dialog("open");` to `$("#boxaddform").dialog();` to make it work the way it does.

Demo  : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TrScN/9/

Comment: Still not firing. if I go to the page that is in my code above, it will fire.

Comment: None. I have checked in chrome and FF

Comment: **However, if I navigate to another page, the link will work.** - what other page? do u have something like this in the other page as well?

Comment: If you look at my posted code, there is a link under the click event.

Comment: instead of dialog("open"), can u try giving an alert() and check if it throws the alert?

Comment: And can you make a fiddle for this pls?

Comment: what do you need to see in fiddle?

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the dialog box. Post your dialog box  html and /or make a fiddle

Comment: Your entire scenario of course. Your problem. That's what must be in the fiddle

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrScN/7/ also you need to go requests > Add box(es) that is the link

Comment: @user1532468 check my edit now. updated answer. u forgot to initialise the dialog box. so `open` didnt work on it

Answer (score 1):

try using live or on function.

```
$(document).live/on('click','a.BA',function(){
// your code
});
```

Comment: No difference. I wonder if it could be a path issue where the link is in the header?

Answer (score 0):

The above answers failed on my side but this worked for me

```
$('body').on('click', '.BA', function() {
console.log("hey");
});
```